# Change music on hold during Dial()

Tags: asterisk

I'm using the parameter `m(mymusic)` in my call to `Dial()` to let the caller hear some music instead of the boring ring tone. However I'd like to have a different music file after some time. The time when the music changes should easily be changeable (by editing a variable), so it is no option to just create a music-on-hold-file which has X seconds of music 1 and then Y seconds of music 2.

What I want is basically this, but without a second `Dial()` and without an actual second call to `${device}`, because that creates two "missed call" entries for one missed call, and it interrupts the phone's ring tone.

```
Set(time_until_new_music=20); 
Dial(${device},${time_until_new_music},gm(music1)); 
if ( "${DIALSTATUS}" == "NOANSWER" ) {
    Dial(${device},,m(music2));
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Hold class can have unlimited number of different sound file of any length

Number of musiconhold classes also unlimited. So you can create your own set for every need

However you can't control from dialplan class info. You can use external steaming app and forward to that app param you need. Require expert level in both asterisk and linux.

Comment: AFAIK, if I use an external "stream" app in musiconhold.conf, the app will be started once (when asterisk starts) and streams the music, so it has no control of when the stream is actually used and when to switch to the other music. 

I know that I can have multiple classes, but I'd need a way to switch to another class after some time.

Comment: No. There is option in musiconhold.conf,you can run one app per thread. You not need switch class, you just need app which play for this class change record acordinly to param you sended.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work:

```
s,1,Set(time_until_new_music=20)
s,2,Dial(${device},${time_until_new_music},gm(music1))
s,3,GotoIf($[${DIALSTATUS}=NOANSWER]?s,4:s,5)
s,4,Dial(${device},,m(music2))
s,5,Hangup()
```